# How to convert HTML to PDF with 6 nested levels w/ pandoc

Tags: lists, pandoc, nesting

The max default nested level for lists are 4. So when I convert a document I receive an error:

> LaTeX error: too deeply nested.

I also use TeXLive, but I do not edit the document with it. I purely convert HTML to PDF with cmd. How can I get more levels without have to actually write in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Please add a complete MWE, that we can see, what you have already tried.

Comment: … and also the command you use with pandoc could be helpful. Why do you use pandoc? There are [other options](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9818093) to convert `html` to `pdf`. Is there a specific feature that you love?

Comment: pandoc myhtml.html -o mypdf.pdf

Comment: @Clément This command works fine but when i get into larger nested lists it doesnt work. I use pandoc because it works very well with mmd which I use in the process of converting a document into html in the first place

Answer (score 1):

You can just increase the maximum depth in the depth check and then declare two extra counters for the number and set up teh default spacing and label for all levels

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{enumv}
\newcounter{enumvi}
\renewcommand\theenumi{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand\theenumii{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand\theenumii{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand\theenumiv{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi.}
\renewcommand\labelenumii{\theenumii.}
\renewcommand\labelenumiii{\theenumii.}
\renewcommand\labelenumiv{\theenumiv.}
\newcommand\labelenumv{\theenumv.}
\newcommand\labelenumvi{\theenumvi.}
\renewcommand\p@enumii{\labelenumi}
\renewcommand\p@enumiii{\labelenumii}
\renewcommand\p@enumiv{\labelenumii}
\renewcommand\p@enumv{\labelenumiv}
\renewcommand\p@enumvi{\labelenumv}
\setlength\leftmargini{1em}
\setlength\leftmarginii{1em}
\setlength\leftmarginiii{1em}
\setlength\leftmarginiv{1em}
\setlength\leftmarginv{1em}
\setlength\leftmarginvi{1em}
\def\enumerate{%
  \ifnum \@enumdepth >
%\thr@@
8
\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@enumdepth\@ne
    \edef\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}%
      \expandafter
      \list
        \csname label\@enumctr\endcsname
        {\usecounter\@enumctr\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate}
\item aaa
\item bbb
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\item ccc
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which template of texlive should i use then?

Comment: @user122832 I could not even guess what you mean by that question sorry. texlive doesn't have anything called templates?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think the OP's  followup question is, how to make Pandoc use these definitions instead of its default LaTeX setup? (I don't know either)

Comment: I guess where do I make these changes. When I use the pandoc command I thought it used LaTeX and the template memoir. If this is or isnt the case i'm still confused of where to make the corrections

Comment: sorry I can show how to typeset deeply nested lists, but I don't know pandoc (and I'm not sure it's really on topic here) to use memoir just change article to memoir in the above.

Comment: @musarithmia This is an example command that I can use to change which template to use. The problem is I dont know which one to use. I have researched and found that enumerate is a good template but it doesn't work either. `pandoc -N --template=mytemplate.tex --variable mainfont="Palatino" --variable sansfont="Helvetica" --variable monofont="Menlo" --variable fontsize=12pt --variable version=1.17.2 MANUAL.txt --latex-engine=xelatex --toc -o example14.pdf`

Comment: This to me is a very powerful way to use latex so i'm not sure how it is off topic.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I still receive an error: too deeply nested

Comment: @user122832 the above example is 6 levels how deep do you need?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't think this will work for me because i need to somehow edit a latex template that will allow me to have 6-7 levels deep. LaTeX's default is 4 I think. I am not using TeX Live editor or an LaTeX editor. I'm merely using LaTeX to Convert HTML to PDF with the pandoc command.                  `pandoc Example.HTML -o Example.pdf` Is this a better explanation?

Comment: Pandoc is using converting your HTML code to LaTeX code and then using the LaTeX program ("engine") to produce a PDF. You have to determine a way to get Pandoc to load David's redefinitions after it loads the rest of its default LaTeX code.

Comment: @user122832 Consider using pandoc to produce tex code first: `pandoc -s -o example.tex example.html`.  Save the portion of David's answer between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` as `nesting.tex` in the same directory as your file. Then open the tex file generated by pandoc, and before `\begin{document}`, add `\input{nesting}`.

Comment: @musarithmia This seems like it will work and I have created both files. But then what command do i use to create the pdf using the example.tex and nesting.tex

Comment: @user122832 `pdflatex example.tex`  would make `example.pdf`

Comment: @musarithmia @davidcarlisle getting `Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle cammands

Comment: @user122832 presumably you have two `\documentclass` commands one will be in the original template you are not supposed to add another

Comment: Hmmmm.... still getting error: too deeply nested

Comment: @user122832 sorry this is getting too far off topic, I can't help with pandoc. perhaps someone else may answer. pandoc is generating tex but asking pandoc questions is like asking C questions in a C program that happens to be generating tex, it's not really on topic here (and needs C, or in this case pandoc) knowledge not tex knowledge.

Comment: I used this command and it somewhat worked but I lost some formatting along the way. `pandoc --templae=nesting.tex example.tex -o example.pdf` It made a pdf but i received `error:\labelenumi undefined` and ` pandoc: error producing pdf`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for all your help... I'm getting there! Thanks (sorry that we traveled off topic)